# sorting tweets in a list based on created at values

Tags: python, twitter

i have a text file(about 600MB) containing tweets in json format collected using search api. I want to sort the tweets based on "created_at" value in tweets and write them to a new file .I have used the code :

```
oldlist=[]
newlist=[]
with open('abc.txt') as f:
    for each in f:
        oldlist.append(json.loads(each))
newlist=(sorted(oldlist,key=lambda k: k['created_at'])).
```

and i can redirect the output using " >>" to a text file.

I have tried it on a smaller file(100MB) and even this takes a long time. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not much in Python. In terms of time complexity this is the best. There are however some tricks you can do to make it *slightly* faster.

Comment: Woaaaaaah. You _definitely_ don't want to call `sorted()`. That returns a copy of your 600 MB list. You should probably switch over to C.

Comment: @Coldspeed: you will *not* copy the data in the list. Sorted makes a *shallow* copy. So it will construct a list of (for instance) 20k references, but the dictionaries themselves (which will probably consume most of the memory) will not be copied.

Comment: Put them into a database and make created_at (part of) a key.

Comment: @wildplasser: usually a database is good for *multiple* aggregates over a dataset. But simply using a database for sorting, will not improve efficiency much, since you first need to set up a connection and then transfer all the data over that connection. At the receiving end indices are built and file IO is done. The insertion process will usually take longer than the sorting.

Comment: Not for sorting, but for storing. Another way would betouse the filesystem as a DB, storing (sorted) tweets in a single (manageable) file per day (or per hour)

Comment: @wildplasser: yeah I agree that if you would like to do *multiple* queries, etc. then it will start paying off. Since a database is an expert system in storing and retrieving (aggregates) of data. Nevertheless a database is *not* optimized to do a single task. So if the OP only wants to sort the file, then he/she should look for something else.

Comment: Once he grows out of memory, he'll have to use either a DB or day/hour-files. (a DB will also allow  searching for `id`, `user_id` , and even `in_reply_to_id`, and reconstruct the entire thread. Fetching a thread costs a few seconds on a raspberry pi using a recursive query/postgresql)

Answer (score -1):

Do you here about the Merge sort? You can divide your file into several small files, sort each of them and after that unite them together using merge sort principe.

Ok, if everybody insists that you should do it in memory, I can advise to use Pandas for it

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('abc.txt')
df.sort(by='created_at')
```

Comment: `sorted(..)` uses TimSort, which usually sorts faster than mergesort.

Comment: do you have enough memory and time to load 600MB dict  and execute in-memory TimSort?

Comment: the dictionary is not 600MB: it is the total file. Parsing it into a dictionary will usually reduce the memory a bit. In the problem statement nowhere is specified that memory is a problem. Furthermore using files will usually make it less efficient, since a HDD/SSD is slower than memory.

Comment: If memory is scarce, maybe sorting the list in-place using `oldlist.sort()` rather than making a new list with `sorted()` could improve things? If it makes a difference between using and not using swapfile…

Comment: @Błotosmętek: note that if you sort the list, with `sorted(..)` you construct a new list, but no new dictionaries. So usually most of the memory will not be a problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem dictionaries in Python is usually a sparse lists, so no more than 30% of it should be filled with data, so 600MB file will take more than 1GB memory

Comment: And if you use several files with merge sort you can trait them as generators and don't put everything into memory

Comment: How about loading your dates as a list, sorting them in place with `list.sort()` and then using the sorted dates to index the rest of the data?

Comment: Numpy would probably do a little better with argsort.